# Converting my smartwatch into a compass for my bike as a accessory

Tags: android, ios, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, wear-os

I have seen a bike navigation system called beeline moto black which shows just a arrow for a navigation with less details and moreover it costs a lot and it is not available in India. Now I want to build something similar to it but as a compass using a cheap smartwatch just for aesthetic pleasure is there any way that I can achieve this and I have experience in developing android apps. I will be using a firebolt round smartwatch which will cost around 2 to 3k.

I tried to fetch the sdk for the smartwatch that is used by that navigation device lol I was stupid.